# CSS DropDown Menu overlaps with underline content

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my DropDown menu
i want a dropdown menu for the logout and i have the css code for it but it wound display completely.

Under the navigationbar, which has the button that should have the dropdown-menu, is a second div .Content located. This div loads the current site content dynamically with php from other .php files. My problem with this is that when i hover over the dropdown-button it cuts off the dropdown-content when reaching the y-axis end of the overlaying navbar div

[image]

my HTML code is this

```css
.NavBarDropDown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.NavBarDropDown-Content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #34495e;
  min-width: 160px;
  min-height: 160px;
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.NavBarDropDown:hover .NavBarDropDown-Content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="NavBarMenu">
  <li class="NavBarButtonIcon NavBarDropDown">
    <a href="index.php?site=account"><img class="NavBarIcon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/34x33" style="height: 34px; width: 33;"> </a>
    <ul>
      <li class="NavBarDropDown-Content">
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="NavBarButtonIcon">
    <a href="index.php?site=notifications"><img class="NavBarIcon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/34x33"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="NavBarButton">
    <a href="index.php?site=classoverview"> Klassen&uuml;bersicht </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have your tags messed up and a whole lot of other problems with the code.

Comment: I edited your code and there was a duplicate </a> closing tag

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? your question is not completely clear

Comment: Your code snippet should have enough code to replicate your problem. Add the relevant css.

Comment: Set z-index of .NavBarDropDown-Content. i.e .NavBarDropDown-Content{z:index:10;} (It can be 10 or any other higher number as long as the content overlapping it has a lower z-index)

Comment: I updated my problem

Comment: I tried it with the z-index but it dont work